# How do I line up 4 divs?

Tags: html, css

I want these divs to be inline.  I was trying to wrap them up in a div and use display:inline-block; to get them in a horizontal row but could not get it to work. I'm really just trying to get my head around positioning and display.  Any help appreciated.

html

```
<div class="small_box_right">

    </div>
    <div class="small_box_right">

    </div>
    <div class="small_box_right">

    </div>
    <div class="small_box_right">

    </div>
```

css

```
.small_box_right {
position: relative;
display:flex;
background: #CDCDB4;
border: 4px solid black;
height:300px;
width:300px;
}
.small_box_right:after, .small_box_right:before {
left: 100%;
top: 50%;
border: solid black;
content: " ";
height: ;
width: ;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
}
.small_box_right:after {
border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
border-left-color: #CDCDB4;;
border-width: 30px;
margin-top: -30px;
}
.small_box_right:before {
border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
border-left-color:black ;
border-width: 36px;
margin-top: -36px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fna4otez/ is that working for you?

Comment: Also you can try this one too : http://jsfiddle.net/fna4otez/1/

Comment: Please tell me if it's working i will write it as an answer. @stee1e

Comment: Yeah that's is great, thanks for the quick response. So you jsut changed that to display:inline-block; am I missing something else as I'm sure I tried that.

Comment: @guvenckardas I suggest using `overflow: auto;` instead of `overflow: scroll;`. BTW, that counts as an answer.

Comment: Yeah these all work.  I haven't used, overflow: yet.  How do I mark these as answers and upvote them. I'm new to SO

Comment: @stee1e, great, I send an answer.

Comment: @stee1e you can mark as an answer like: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147532

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div) or a host of others found by searching SO.

Comment: Rob - Yeah i did do a search but struggled to find anything.  I think as my CSS vocabulary grows I'd be able to find what I need better.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fna4otez/1/)

html:

```
<div class="box-cover">
<div class="small_box_right">

</div>
<div class="small_box_right">

</div>
<div class="small_box_right">

</div>
<div class="small_box_right">

</div>

</div>
```

css:

```
  .box-cover{
        position: relative;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 1550px;
    }

    .small_box_right {
        position: relative;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #CDCDB4;
        border: 4px solid black;
        height:300px;
        width:300px;
        margin-right: 50px;
    }
    .small_box_right:after, .small_box_right:before {
        left: 100%;
        top: 50%;
        border: solid black;
        content: " ";
        height: ;
        width: ;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .small_box_right:after {
        border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
        border-left-color: #CDCDB4;;
        border-width: 30px;
        margin-top: -30px;
    }
    .small_box_right:before {
        border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
        border-left-color:black ;
        border-width: 36px;
        margin-top: -36px;
    }
```